# Main class property is null in main class when value is assigned in sub class in JAVA

Tags: java, android

I am new to JAVA, but have experience in other languages like C/C++ . I am studying android and now creating an application which access a JSON web service.

My class code is below :

```
public class AsycTaskCall {

private final JSONObject jsonObject;
private final Context context;

public static String results;

public AsycTaskCall(Context ctx, JSONObject jobject)
{
    this.jsonObject = jobject;
    this.context = ctx;
}

public String call()
{
    new WebServiceTask().execute("");
    Log.d("RESULTS_CALL", "Results : " + results); //results is null here
    return this.results;
}

private class WebServiceTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        JsonWebService jsonWebService = new JsonWebService(context);
        return jsonWebService.callWebService(jsonObject);
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        try
        {
            JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(result);
            String status = jo.getString("success");

            results = result;

            if (status == "true")
            {
               Log.d("RESULTS", " Result : " + result + " : Results " + results); // results is fine here also
            }
            else
            {
                Log.d("RESULT_STATUS", "False");
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    }
  }
```

I created this class, because my application will be calling the web services in lots of places, so i wanted to created one single class, and pass it the JSONObject, and then this class call the webservice async.

Ever thing is working fine, and i got the required results, but now i want to return the result to calling activity. For this purpose i created a

```
public static String results;
```

property and save the returned string from webservice in this variable. This variable has the data in the sub class WebServiceTask  , but in this same variable the data is null in the main class, or when i return it in the main class call function , it is null.

Please advice me how to fix this problem.

Thank you

Comment: Java is not C.  For purposes of understanding the normal use of the language, assume that every variable belongs to a class - your choice is merely between having it be shared by every instance of the class (static) or be unique to each instance of the class.  It sounds like you may have accidentally created distinct variables with the same name belonging to difference classes.  Or perhaps you simply have not assigned the variable before trying to read it.

Comment: I know java is not C / C++ , i just mentioned that i have knowledge of OOP. Nope, in all my code where i am calling this class call method, i dont have any variable same as the results.

Comment: Try using an [`IntentService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) as shown [here](http://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/send-request.html). How to get results back is explained [here](http://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/report-status.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `WebServiceTask` is scheduled for execution in the background, so the results might not be available immediately. But you try to fetch the `results` in the next line, right after queuing the execution. This won't work in most cases.

[AsyncTask documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#execute%28Params...%29):

> Note: this function schedules the task on a queue for a single background thread or pool of threads depending on the platform version. When first introduced, AsyncTasks were executed serially on a single background thread. Starting with DONUT, this was changed to a pool of threads allowing multiple tasks to operate in parallel.

You could call the [`get()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get%28%29) method of the executed `AsyncTask` if you want to wait for completion and receive the value directly after queuing the task. But that will render the idea of a background task quite useless and may block your UI thread, depending on where you invoke the `call()` from.

Comment: Indeed, one would normally assume that the results would not be available for some time.  Nor could one wait (from the UI thread) for them to be, as that would defeat the purpose of using an AsyncTask.  Rather what is needed is to trigger an event/message back on the main thread when the task is completed - and AsyncTask has a built in capability for that - onPostExecute().

Comment: @nif , thanks for the good explanation. I am studying the documentation and now trying your proposed solution. I hope it will help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That is an unusual style

```
new WebServiceTask().execute("");
```

There is no reference kept, like in

```
WebServiceTask webServiceTask = new WebServiceTask();
webServiceTask.execute("");
```

so I wonder how long it survives the garbage collection, considering the task itself needs some time to execute.

Maybe try a

```
WebServiceTask webServiceTask;
```

in your declaration part at the beginning and then use

```
webServiceTask = new WebServiceTask();
webServiceTask.execute("");
```

Using globals and statics like this will probably give you some headaches, once you have many calls going on.

Comment: There is a general point here, but this is unlikely to explain the problem actually experienced.

Comment: I think he saws the branch on which he sits. A debugger session would clarify what happens.

Comment: Or not, as it's likely a race condition and multithreaded debugging is as likely to change those as illuminate them.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this static variable as ClassName.results Or you can make results only public not static and assign value by context like ((ClassName)ctx).results = "value"